# import axios from './lib/axios.js'; SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, axios

What did i do wrong in my server.ts?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const axios = require('axios');
console.log(axios);


...
```

node version

```
$ node -v
v12.9.1
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "start": "ts-node ./src/server/server.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "eslint": "^4.6.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}
```

but when i start a server by `npm start`

C:\dev-projects\testing\vue-server\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
at Object.require.extensions. [as .js] (C:\dev-projects\testing\vue-server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
at Object. (C:\dev-projects\testing\vue-server\src\server\server.ts:5:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
at Module.m._compile (C:\dev-projects\testing\vue-server\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)

i alr reinstall node_modules some times, trying imporst axios, install another versions of axios, and even trying do it .js/.mjs files.

.but it didnt help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default build of axios assumes you're using ESM (JavaScript's native module format), but you're using CommonJS (Node.js's old module format). You have at least two options:

1. Switch to [native modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (`import`/`export` rather than `require()`),

   or
2. Refer to the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) for how to load axios using CommonJS, which lists various CDN options and also says this:

   > Prebuilt CommonJS modules for direct importing with require (if your module bundler failed to resolve them automatically)
   >
   > ```
   > const axios = require('axios/dist/browser/axios.cjs'); // browser
   > const axios = require('axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'); // node
   > ```

---

Separately:

> ```bash
> $ node -v
> v12.9.1
> ```

That's a markedly out of date version of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), v12 reached end-of-life 30 April 2022. The current LTS is v20.10.0; the most recent non-LTS is v21.2.0.